# Removal of List from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, machine-learning, k-means

```
    ProArticle                                          Vector

0   Iran jails blogger 14 years An Iranian weblogg...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1   UK gets official virus alert site A rapid aler...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
2   OSullivan could run Worlds Sonia OSullivan ind...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
3   Mutant book wins Guardian prize A book evoluti...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
4   Microsoft seeking spyware trojan Microsoft inv...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
```

The above is the data.head() snippet from a vectorized news article.

`type(data.Vector[0])` is `list`

I need to use KMeans clustering on this Vectorized data, but the lists won't let me.

`data.Vector.shape` is `179`, and `data.Vector[0].shape` is `8868`.

How can I remove the list, or if I can't, then how can I use it to cluster the given data? Perhaps I could get a dataframe in the following way to start, followed by running PCA on it.

Expected Output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please include expected output. Do you want to split every element of your `Vector` and `ProArticle` to a seperate row?

Comment: I have added the expected output.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it seems that you want to do, is to create a 2D numpy array out of a Pandas column that contains lists of numbers. In most cases you can treat a Pandas column as a list or 1-dimensional Numpy array. here, you can use [`vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.vstack.html#numpy.ma.vstack) to stack the separate lists as rows:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     "ProArticle": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
...     "Vector": [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
... })
>>> vs = np.vstack(df.Vector)
>>> vs
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

So this results in an array that you can use directly with sklearn's KMeans:

```
>>> kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
>>> kmeans.fit_predict(vs)
array([1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

If you still want to have the intermediate result as a Pandas dataframe, you can use `apply` to create Pandas series of each list; according to [`apply`'s documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) this results in a DataFrame:

```
>>> df.Vector.apply(pd.Series)
   0  1
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
```

You can then get the same Numpy array by accessing the `.values` member of the resulting DataFrame. However, this is by far slower than the `vstack` solution, 1 milliseconds versus 25.4 *micro*seconds on my machine.

Comment: Sorry maybe my question was not put correctly. I have made some edits.

Comment: I expanded the answer after your edits, did that help?